# iOS Run two asynchronous method if failed

Tags: ios, asynchronous, authentication

I have a scenario where I need to quiet refresh auth token (relogin) again if it expired when I accessing other API but I'm having a hard time thinking how to code this without creating redundant codes for every APIs even though the flow is similar.

When user has expired auth token > call paid API A (return 401 unauthorised) > relogin again > call paid API A (run successfully)

I'm having difficult in wrapping my mind to call paid API A **the second time** with less code and not falling into infinite loop trap. Is there any method useful for this case like NSNotification center?

Note: I need to use API in this format from AFNetworkinglogin

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)getApiA:(CallbackBlock)block{

CallbackBlock _block = [block copy];

NSString *urlString = [[NSURL URLWithString:GET_API_A_URL relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:HOME_URL]] absoluteString];

return [self GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSDictionary *response = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;


    BLOCK_SAFE_RUN(block, response, nil, task);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

    if([self unauthorizedAccess:task]){ //401
        ***//call Login once again > run getApiA again***
    }else if ([self forbiddenAccess:task]){ //403

    }


    BLOCK_SAFE_RUN(block, nil, error, task);
}];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If i get it right you could split it into 2 methods. And pass a bool for trying again. e.g.:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)getApiA:(id)block {
    NSString *urlString = [[NSURL URLWithString:GET_API_A_URL relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:HOME_URL]] absoluteString];
    return [self doApiACallWithURL:urlString firstTry:YES completion:block];
}

- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)doApiACallWithURL:(NSString *)url firstTry:(BOOL)first completion:(CallbackBlock)completion {
    __weak typeof(self) wself = self;
    return [self GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSDictionary *response = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

        BLOCK_SAFE_RUN(block, response, nil, task);

    }        failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

        if ([wself unauthorizedAccess:task]) { //401
            if (first) {
                [wself doApiACallWithURL:url firstTry:NO completion:completion];
            }
        } else if ([wself forbiddenAccess:task]) { //403

        }

        BLOCK_SAFE_RUN(block, nil, error, task);
    }];
}
```

and use a weak self for blocks is in most cases a good idea.